# Where should you put the logic in an Express app, upon reaching a route?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, logic

I've been reading some Node.JS, Express tutorials and I realized something funny.

When it comes to doing some logic in the app, they always seem to suggest putting the logic in the route for when the request arrives. For example, in [this tutorial](http://shamadeh.com/blog/web/2014/06/26/NodeRestAPITutorial.html), some of logic even gets pretty long:

```
    //Delete a book
    app.delete( '/api/books/:id', function( request, response ) {
        BookModel.findById( request.params.id, function( err, book ) {
            return book.remove( function( err ) {
                if( !err ) {
                    console.log( 'Book removed' );
                    return response.send( '' );
                } else {
                    console.log( err );
                    return response.send('ERROR');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Is there a better way to organize this logic? For example, can you put the logic in another file (considering my project will need a lot of logic in some of the routes)? And if yes, how can you reference it into the routes file?

Comment: Just move the controller to an external file and require it. [Prime example](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/routes/frontend.js).

Comment: @BenFortune thanks for the link. It seems similar to what user3776269 suggests. I'll try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try somthing like this:

```
// app.js

var routes = require('./routes.js');
app.delete( '/api/books/:id', routes.book.delete);
app.get(    '/api/books/:id', routes.book.getBook);

// routes.js

module.exports = {
    books: {
        delete: function(request, response){
            BookModel.findById( request.params.id, function( err, book ) {
                return book.remove( function( err ) {
                    if( !err ) {
                        console.log( 'Book removed' );
                        return response.send( '' );
                    } else {
                        console.log( err );
                        return response.send('ERROR');
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        getBook: function(req, res){
            .....
        }
    },
    user: {
        .....
    }
}
```